# Date-Based Conditional Tag

Tags: conditional-content

I'd like to have a conditional tag that is something like this:

```
<?php if (is_single()&&is_older_than_october_2011()){do this}; ?>
```

The part I'm trying to highlight is the is_older_than_october_2011() aspect.  There doesn't appear to be any conditional tag that WP offers which has this functunality?

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 2):

Here is function I have for old posts:

```
function is_old_post( $days = 14 ) {

    if( !is_single() )
        return false;

    $id = get_the_ID();
    $date = get_post_field( 'post_date', $id );

    if( strtotime( $date ) < strtotime( "-{$days} days" ) )
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Not tested, but you can probably tweak condition to be something like:

```
if( strtotime( $date ) < strtotime( 'October 2011' ) )
```